# .net utility is not functioning as expected when scheduled in Control M

Tags: .net, winforms, control-m

We have developed a .net win forms application which is used to migrate files from a source location to target path based on the inputs from an SQL table.
The application is working fine when it is executed manually and all the relevant files are getting migrated.
During this phase - the application updates the migration status in SQL table as
- Migration in Progress - when we start the application
- Migration Completed - When all the files are migrated
- Error - if there are any failures

when we are scheduling it via control - M, the status in SQl is being updated by application as "Migration in progress" and the application is remaining in that state ideally till we kill the job and files are not getting migrated.

The job is written in a .bat file as below
net use \server path with service account credentials
start E:\DocUtility\Migrate doc utility.exe

PS: In a simple way, application is working as expected when run manually and not running properly when scheduled via control -M

can you please suggest what might be the reason for this issue, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with application name which was scheduled in the batch file.
The application name was containing spaces by which Control - M was unable to trigger it.
I have removed the spaces in the application name and from then Control -M was able to trigger it without any issues.